# Can I plug text into HTML from elsewhere?

Tags: html

I'm new to web development and I'm working on my second website. I feel it should be a basic question and probably have already gotten addressed somewhere on Stack Overflow. However I can't find anything directly relevant, due to a lack of precise description. The problem is:

Because I'm doing copywriting along the way, frequently I find myself needing to update the copy inside the HTML code wrapped deep inside many div's. It's quite inconvenient; and because of texts, codes can sometimes get messy.

I wonder if there's a simple way to leave a "handle" in place of texts inside HTML code, "plugging in" text from elsewhere, like plugging in style from CSS? I suppose it should work in a concept similar to what a CMS have.

Comment: You can give a div any ID you want, so long as it's unique to the whole page. `<div id="body">`

Comment: you can try using jQuery .load() method to load the copy from a file...

Comment: to be honest, although I posted an answer, I'm still not sure what exactly you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use .html to plug text and symbol to html page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Your page</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">     
  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
     $("#statictext").html('<b>jQuery</b>');
      $("#symbol").html('&copy;');
    });
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="statictext"></div>
 <div id="symbol"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna accept this as the answer because using jQuery the code is much shorter and look so much neater. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `id` HTML attribute. You can use it like this from javascript (i'm using js since you don't specify a language):

```
var yourelement = document.getElementById('yourelementid');

yourelement.textContent = "Yer text";
```

with your html being:

```
<div id="yourelementid"></div>
```

with the element being a `div` or any other element that can have text content.

If you need to insert HTML, you can do it through `.innerHTML` or, preferrably, manipulate the DOM, by adding and removing elements. CSS also has an `attr()` property function, which allows you to set an arbitrary property on an HTML element (such as `piece="textstuff"`, with the css being `content: attr(piece)`).

You can also construct elements and append them (again, if what you want is to insert HTML markup) by using `.appendChild` and `.removeChild`.

Comment: I've tried and it worked! Thanks for the answer and sorry about my vague question. I just needed one place to place all the copy when I constantly fiddle with them during the development, not wanting to dive into the HTML code every time when I change something.